# Arzela-Ascoli Theorem: pointwise boundedness at one point

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n$ forms a sequence of equicontinuous functions in $C^0$, and domain is $[a,b]$. For $p$ belongs to $[a,b]$, we have $f_n(p)$ to be a bounded sequence in $R$. Prove $f_n$ to be uniformly bounded.

What I can do is to use connectedness of $[a,b]$ (chain connected) and pointwise bounded at one point to prove pointwise boundedness at every point. Then use pointwise boundedness and compactness of $[a,b]$ to show uniformly bounded.

But is there any method that we can avoid the use of chain connected to show $f_n$ is pointwise bounded at every point (i.e. only using equicontinuous and compactness of the domain). We can have another condition for the Arzela-Ascoli theorem to be true, if we can avoid the use of connectedness. (Clearly, one condition is that pointwise bounded at every point, but I am wondering if we can extend it to pointwise bounded at one single point, given the compact domain).

Thanks!

Here is the question, and part b asks a weaker condition. So is boundedness at one point enough or we need pointwise bounded for all points?
[image]

And the chain-connected argument comes from a previous question:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the statement for equicontinuity instantiated with $\varepsilon=1$. This creates an open cover of $[a,b]$. Compactness allows you to extract a finite subcover. Then $|f_n(x)|=|f_n(p)-f_n(p)+f_n(x)| \leq |f_n(p)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(p)|$. But $|f_n(x)-f_n(p)| \leq N$ where $N$ is the number of elements in our subcover, and $|f_n(p)|$ is bounded by hypothesis.

This is the standard trick used to prove things like the Heine-Cantor theorem. I'm not sure if this is actually what you meant by "chain connectedness", though.

Edit: Yeah, this is pretty much the chain-connectedness argument, just expanded out in this special case.

Comment: I have added a picture for the chain connected part

Comment: So if the domain is just a general compact set, we do not have such argument?

Comment: And answer to part b question 18 is just pointwise bounded at all points?

Comment: @12345 It couldn't be with just a general compact set, because in that case you could have boundedness in one connected component and unboundedness in the other. As for part b, I assume the best you can do is a decomposition into chain-connected components.

Comment: Hi, can you show in detail how you got |fn(x)−fn(p)|≤N with compact?

Comment: @12345 You probably can't do it. I was using the fact that we're dealing with $[a,b]$ in particular. If you had, say, a union of two compact intervals, the argument could break down, because the $\delta$ could be so small that $p$ can't "communicate" with the other connected component.

Comment: But how to show that with [a,b] by its compactness? I am a bit confused now, since I only used the chain connected property.Thx!

Comment: @12345 It doesn't follow just from compactness. What happens is that you get a finite subcover, then chain connectedness lets you "jump" from one open set in the cover to the next, each time increasing $|f_n|$ by at most $1$. Since there are only finitely many sets in the cover and you also have chain connectedness, you can reach any other point in $[a,b]$ in this manner and obtain a bound. As I said, just compactness is not sufficient.